# File watcher for compass in phpstorm

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, phpstorm, file-watcher

i've been lately struggling with phpstorm file watchers. I'm trying to set up a Compass scss file watcher to work with this folder structure

```
project
    themes
        default-bootstrap
            sass
               modules
               etc
            css
               modules
               etc
```

As you can see the folders in "sass" folder should be mirrored in "css" folder.I just cant figure out what should I put in arguments, working directory, output path boxes :/ to get it working :/ I've created scope which recursively includes from "default-bootstrap" folder but that's it. I dont know what next :/

For example when I edit some scss file in modules folder I want phpstorm compile it to the css/modules folder. I have ruby, sass and compass installed and configured in phpstorm

Can anyone please help me ? The documentation from Jetbrains is not really helpful here ://

Comment: In my case, project path was not correct in compass watcher ( watcher by php storm)

Answer (score 0):

My SCSS watcher settings based on yous structure:

```
Scope: Project Files
Program: PATH_TO_COMPASS
Arguments:  --no-cache --update $FileName$:$ProjectFileDir$/themes/default-bootstrap/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
Working directory: $ProjectFileDir$/themes/default-bootstrap/sass
Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/themes/default-bootstrap/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

`$ProjectFileDir$` is equivalent to `/home/{username}/{projects_path}/project`

Comment: Well this settings lead to this

/usr/bin/compass --no-cache --update global.scss:/Users/deepress/Sites/Surfstore-presta 1.6/themes/default-bootstrap/css/global.css
Error: invalid option: --no-cache

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Also can you explain to me what does the ":" means in this syntax ?

Comment: I don't know what does it means, was the default. I'm using the sass-lang.com and the above settings work for me.
Try to put this in arguments: compile $FileName$:$ProjectFileDir$/themes/default-bootstrap/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

Comment: Tried this but i get "The individual stylesheets must be in the same directory"

Comment: what does your config.rb looks like? '--no-cache --update' are not valid compass options. I normally use <path/to/config.rb directory> $FilePath$ as 'Arguments' field value

Answer (score 0):

My SASS watcher settings (working :-)), based on your path structure:

```
Arguments: --update $FileName$:$ProjectFileDir$/themes/default-bootstrap/css/$FileDirPathFromParent(sass)$$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

Output paths to refresh: $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map

Working directory: $FileDir$
```